# how many times HDD can be formatted?

Tags: hard-drive

**MY friend told me that even when you format a HDD some file still remains there in compressed form in the heap . So, eventually at one point our memory gets full with those compressed file. I don't understand???** 
But if I guess then ,How a recovery tool is able to extract the formatted file in HDD which means the file must be there in some format in the memory.

Comment: Nothing you said makes any sense whatsoever.  Formatting a hdd has nothing to do with compression or a heap.

Comment: As many times as you want.

Comment: `MY friend told me that even when you format a HDD some file still remains there in compressed form in the heap` -- Your friend is incorrect.  Formatting a partition, which is also called a "filesystem volume", and often called a "drive", involves writing some specific data to the drive.  Re-formatting will write that same data to the drive.  I endorse the last sentence of @Zippy's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is clearly talking out of his posterior.

'Heap' is memory management. Its a *programming* concept (so kind of out of my depth) and there's a [great answer covering all that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap). What you really need to know is this has *nothing* to do with hardware or hard drives.

"How many times can a HDD be formatted" is not really a useful question. Its something like "How long is a piece of string" or maybe even "How large a bundle can I tie with a piece of string".

It has nothing to do with memory.

"Recovery" relies on the tendancy of modern tools to be clever. Rewriting every single 'bit' on a drive is silly.

A good anology to use is to think of a hard drive as the library. *Regular* deletion is simply marking the shelves (space) as unused, and tearing up the index cards. The books are *left* there until the space is needed, then thrown into the library furnace. So if you need a bit of data, and its not yet been overwritten it may be still there. (Some modern drives are self encrypting. They go further by having the books in ancient arkadian, and burning the english-arkadian dictionary instead). In short, unless explicitly securely deleted, or overwritten, deleted data is still there.

At no point does this have anything to do with memory. I can install the same drive in another system, with no connection, and still recover data.

Traditional hard drives typically die due to electrical or component failure - often head crashes. SSDs *can* wear out gradually, but I leave this as an exercise to the reader to research.

I do suggest the next time your friend says this, to perhaps consider the possibility he's making this up as he goes along.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a simple format of a hdd does not ERASE all the data. It just marks it as available space for any new data that needs a place to be written to. Therfore yes the data/files are still there. With special software tools which you can find on the internet you can recover files from a hdd that have been formated providing it has not been overwritten by newly added data/files. A HDD can be formatted or reformatted as many times as you need or until it's mechanical or electronics parts fails.